# Email Newsletter: Image size changing in Outlook 2016 (Desktop) on mouseover

Tags: html, email, outlook, html-table, newsletter

I am working on a newsletter design, in which I need to place two images side by side (under the Find a Camp Today section on the attached screenshot). I am using tables, tr and td to so. More precisely I am using a two column table to place my images in. But Outlook on Desktop is behaving in a very weird way. When I rollover my mouse on these images, the size of the images changes, and I feel a jump in the page.

On top of this section, there is a three column section with images. But that works perfectly fine on mouseover.

I even tried stripping my code down, and removed the  tags from around the images, but even using a simple  tag is creating the same issue. Can anyone please help?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml"
xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office">
<head>
    <!--[if gte mso 9]><xml>
    <o:OfficeDocumentSettings>
    <o:AllowPNG/>
    <o:PixelsPerInch>96</o:PixelsPerInch>
    </o:OfficeDocumentSettings>
</xml><![endif]-->
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<!--[if !mso]><!-->
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
<!--<![endif]-->
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<title></title>

<style type="text/css">

@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {

    #header img {
        width: 100% !important;
        max-width: 600px !important;
    }

    #threeSteps img {
        width: 50px !important;
        height: auto !important;
    }
}

</style>
    <!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
    <style type="text/css">
        table {border-collapse: collapse;}
    </style>
    <![endif]-->
</head>
<body style="margin: 0 !important; padding: 0; background-color: #284055;">
    <center class="wrapper" style="width: 100%; table-layout: fixed; color: #284055; font-family:arial,'helvetica neue',helvetica,sans-serif;">
        <div class="webkit" style="width: 100%; max-width: 600px; margin: 0 auto;">
            <!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
            <table width="600" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="border-collapse: collapse;">
            <tr>
            <td>
                <![endif]-->
                <table width="95%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0"; class="outerTable" align="center" style="table-layout: fixed; max-width: 600px; Margin: 0 auto; border-collapse: collapse;">
                    <tbody>
                        <tr id = "preHeader">
                            <td style="padding: 18px 0 9px 0">
                                <table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" style="border-collapse: collapse;">
                                    <tbody>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td style="width: 55%;">
                                                <div>
                                                    <a href="http://www.ussportscamps.com/" target="_blank"><img align="none" height="52" src="https://gallery.mailchimp.com/29e5ee226282df721575ec2a2/images/c92fc6ee-674b-4bde-8dce-096423d1f338.png" style="width: 150px; height: 52px; margin: 0px;" width="150"></a>
                                                </div>
                                                <p style="margin-top: 3px;color: #FFFFFF; font-size:10px;">Offering the best locations across the country</p>
                                            </td>
                                            <td style="width: 45%; text-align: right">
                                                <div class="phoneNo" style="text-align: right;">
                                                    <img align="none" src="https://gallery.mailchimp.com/29e5ee226282df721575ec2a2/images/936029f6-3875-447b-a16b-8d5f56dc1019.png" style="width: 12px; height: 12px; margin: 0px; margin-right:3px;">
                                                    <span style="color: #FFFFFF; font-family:arial,helvetica neue,helvetica,sans-serif; line-height: 14px;"><a href="#" style="display:table-cell; font-size:14px; vertical-align:middle; color: #FFFFFF; text-decoration: none;">1-800-645-3226</a></span>
                                                </div>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </tbody>
                                </table>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                        <tr id="header">
                            <td>
                                <a href="" style="display: block;"><img src="https://gallery.mailchimp.com/29e5ee226282df721575ec2a2/images/fbab6265-6181-4b4a-a23e-f0b120c63bb5.jpg" width="600" style="display: block; width: 100%; max-width: 600px;"></a>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr id="introText" style="background-color: #FFFFFF; border: 1px solid #FFFFFF; border-left: 0; border-right: 0;">
                            <td>
                                <p style="padding: 18px; color: #97a5b1; font-size: 16px; line-height: 22px; text-align: center;">Searching for a camp at a top college? Looking for something at a driving distance from your local community? We’ve got all your needs covered.</p>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr id="threeSteps" style="background-color: #FFFFFF; border: 1px solid #FFFFFF; border-left: 0; border-right: 0;">
                            <td>
                                <table width="90%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" style="width: 90%; margin: auto; border-collapse: collapse; line-height: 16px;">
                                    <tbody>
                                        <tr style="text-align: center;">
                                            <td width="33.33%" valign="top">
                                                <div style="margin: 0 10px">
                                                    <img src="https://gallery.mailchimp.com/29e5ee226282df721575ec2a2/images/a4274d78-edd8-4fb0-a184-07a14a61658d.png">
                                                    <p style="font-size: 12px;">Select a Sport</p>
                                                </div>
                                            </td>
                                            <td width="33.33%" valign="top">
                                                <div style="margin: 0 10px">
                                                    <img src="https://gallery.mailchimp.com/29e5ee226282df721575ec2a2/images/29b4889a-f35c-438e-b888-9d3bc52f9e36.png">
                                                    <p style="font-size: 12px;">Explore Programs & Locations</p>
                                                </div>
                                            </td>
                                            <td width="33.33%" valign="top">
                                                <div style="margin: 0 10px">
                                                    <img src="https://gallery.mailchimp.com/29e5ee226282df721575ec2a2/images/70d34e64-3c9f-4b55-a1ec-39cb24ec4873.png">
                                                    <p style="font-size: 12px;">Reserve your camp</p>
                                                </div>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </tbody>
                                </table>  
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr id="learnMoreLink" style="background-color: #FFFFFF; border: 1px solid #FFFFFF; border-right: 0; border-left: 0;">
                            <td>
                                <div style="padding-top: 12px; text-align: center;">
                                    <a href="#" style="text-decoration: none;"><span style="color: #2982cf; font-size: 12px;">Learn More</span></a>
                                </div>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr class="separator" style="background-color: #FFFFFF; border: 1px solid #FFFFFF; border-right: 0; border-left: 0;">
                            <td>
                                <hr style="width: 90%; margin: 30px auto; border: 0; border-top: 1px solid #e9ecee;">
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr id="sportsWidgetHeading" style="background-color: #FFFFFF; border: 1px solid #FFFFFF; border-left: 0; border-right: 0;">
                            <td>
                                <h2 style="margin: 0; color: #284055; font-size: 16px; text-align: center; text-transform: uppercase;">Find a Camp Today</h2>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr id="sportsWidgets" style="background-color: #FFFFFF; border: 1px solid #FFFFFF; border-left: 0; border-right: 0;">
                            <td>
                                <table width="90%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" style="max-width: 580px; margin: 20px auto;">
                                    <tbody>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td width="49%;" style="width: 49%;">
                                                <div style="padding-right: 9px; padding-bottom: 18px;">
                                                    <a href="http://www.ussportscamps.com/tennis/" target="_blank" style=" text-decoration: none;">
                                                        <img src="https://gallery.mailchimp.com/29e5ee226282df721575ec2a2/images/aee9ab4d-d626-43c0-924a-2808c3bf32f7.jpg" style="display: block; width: 100%; max-width: 264px; margin:0;">
                                                        <div style="margin: 0; padding: 7px; border-bottom: 3px solid #d4d9dd; color: #FFFFFF;font-family: Helvetica;font-size: 12px;font-weight: normal;text-align: left; text-transform: uppercase; background-color: #e97526;"><span>Tennis Camps</span>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </a>
                                                </div>    
                                            </td>
                                            <td width="49%;" style="width: 49%;">
                                                <div style="padding-left: 9px; padding-bottom: 18px;">
                                                    <a href="http://www.ussportscamps.com/tennis/" target="_blank" style=" text-decoration: none;">
                                                        <img src="https://gallery.mailchimp.com/29e5ee226282df721575ec2a2/images/aee9ab4d-d626-43c0-924a-2808c3bf32f7.jpg" style="display: block; width: 100%; max-width: 264px; margin:0;">
                                                        <div style="margin: 0; padding: 7px; border-bottom: 3px solid #d4d9dd; color: #FFFFFF;font-family: Helvetica;font-size: 12px;font-weight: normal;text-align: left; text-transform: uppercase; background-color: #e97526;"><span>Tennis Camps</span>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </a>
                                                </div>    
                                            </td>    
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td width="49%;" style="width: 49%;">
                                                <div style="padding-right: 9px; padding-bottom: 18px;">
                                                    <a href="#" target="_blank" style=" text-decoration: none;">
                                                        <img src="https://gallery.mailchimp.com/29e5ee226282df721575ec2a2/images/aee9ab4d-d626-43c0-924a-2808c3bf32f7.jpg" style="display: block; width: 100%; max-width: 264px; margin:0;">
                                                        <div style="margin: 0; padding: 7px; border-bottom: 3px solid #d4d9dd; color: #FFFFFF;font-family: Helvetica;font-size: 12px;font-weight: normal;text-align: left; text-transform: uppercase; background-color: #e97526;"><span>Tennis Camps</span>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </a>
                                                </div>    
                                            </td>
                                            <td width="49%;" style="width: 49%;">
                                                <div style="padding-left: 9px; padding-bottom: 18px;">
                                                    <a href="#" target="_blank" style=" text-decoration: none;">
                                                        <img src="https://gallery.mailchimp.com/29e5ee226282df721575ec2a2/images/aee9ab4d-d626-43c0-924a-2808c3bf32f7.jpg" style="display: block; width: 100%; max-width: 264px; margin:0;">
                                                        <div style="margin: 0; padding: 7px; border-bottom: 3px solid #d4d9dd; color: #FFFFFF;font-family: Helvetica;font-size: 12px;font-weight: normal;text-align: left; text-transform: uppercase; background-color: #e97526;"><span>Tennis Camps</span>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </a>
                                                </div>    
                                            </td>    
                                        </tr>

                                    </tbody>
                                </table>
                            </td>

                        </tr>
                    </table>
                    <!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <![endif]-->
    </div>
</center>
</body>
```

Comment: Using your code provided I am unable to reproduce the issue..

Comment: When sending email don't do styling with `<style>` and `</style>` tags and don't use `class="` for styling. Many email clients won't honor the CSS when done that way.